# Unable to checkin , checkout and delete the aspx in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I'm using sharepoint 2013

I need to edit the aspx page but when i click the file below error occur

[image]

I try with below method but no use

1. Discard check out show me " first checkout the file"
2. SP Designer- file already in check-In unable to Checkout
3. library settings-> Manage files which have no checked in version - show yellow page error.

any alternate solution available to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Go to the page itself in your web browser and make sure you have full owner permissions of the page and site.

`http://<domain>/Knowledge/News/Pages/default.aspx`

Override the checkout next to "Site Actions" by clicking on Page -> Override Checkout and it should work.

If NOT: The default.aspx masterpage is probably not in the "Pages" folder. Try opening the below URL into SP Designer (take the "/Pages" out):

`http://<domain>/Knowledge/News/default.aspx`

And this should work.

Comment: Have you tried my method? Try it and report your findings, please.

Comment: Override checkout  - "Cannot Complete this action The file "Pages/default.aspx" is not checked out"

Comment: SP Designer - "The folder name is not valid"

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clear cache of a SharePoint designer from the machine you are opening it.

The cache is composed of these 2 folders:

1. %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
2. %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

Just delete the content of these folders.

Comment: its not working for me ,